# Парсинг сайта, нажатие на кнопку

Tags: python, парсер

Нужно спарсить данные с сайта 'https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=освіта' но там можно спарсить только 10 строк, потом что бы продолжать парсинг надо нажать на кнопку. Как мне лучше всего это сделать? Вот мой код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=освіта'

HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
'accept':'*/*'}

HOST = 'https://prozorro.gov.ua'

from selenium import webdriver



def get_html(url,params = None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers =  HEADERS,params = params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'items-list')
    links = []
    for item in items:
        links.append({
            'link': HOST + item.find('a',class_ = 'items-list--header').get('href')
        })




        print(len(links))
    print(links)
def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Ошибка')

parser()
```

Comment: так там же есть готовое апи, ничего парсить не нужно, все доступно

Comment: @KoVadim дело говорит. А вообще кнопка чисто на js сделана. В этом случае bs4 вам ничем не поможет. Нужно использовать selenium или что-то подобное, что управляет настоящим браузером

Comment: либо смотреть, что под кнопкой спрятано (а там скорее всего обычный запрос на сервер, на то же апи)